# how we define auto increment id in riak ts

Tags: riak-ts

How we create table in Riak TS for auto_increment id such as in mysql we create:::as example---

**create table Department(id int auto_increment not null,departmentName varchar(9));**

is there any way to create table with **AUTO_INCREMENT**

CAN ANYONE TELL ME ?

Answer (score 1):

Riak TS (as of version 1.4) does not feature the ability to create an auto incrementing ID. I highly recommend reading the Riak TS documents for more information. The following page will give you a good introduction to creating tables and the supported data types: http://docs.basho.com/riak/ts/latest/using/planning/